# Catchable fatal error in appcloud free theme by Tokokoo

Tags: php, themes, dashboard, fatal-error

I have been attempting to make this theme work, Kelontong by Tokokoo, as seen here :

http://stylishwebdesigner.com/6-free-wordpress-ecommerce-themes-to-create-an-online-   marketplace-for-your-product/

However, after uploading the theme to my supervisor's wordpress site, and installing and activating the theme, the homepage displays this message where the photo slideshow should be:

**Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/valeh/vene.com/wp-content/themes/appcloudfree-2/home.php on line 25**

When I check that line of code in the file, this is what is shown:
`<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>" name="product_id" />`

**Could someone please tell me what is causing this error?**

Also, I'm not sure if this is related or if the theme is just completely broken, but the theme's panel on the dashboard of my site does not seem to be functioning at all either, it doesn't seem that any of it has a buttonmode, as in i cannot click on any of the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the theme you mentioned isn't what you get if you click download. The actual theme Kelontong is a Premium Theme. You can find it here:
http://tokokoo.com/portfolio/kelontong/

If you are using Kelontong that you found as a free download, it's probably a "Ripped" version. If this is the case, you probably have more problems than the error you speak of. You should [download the plug-in used by the WP Theme Review Team called ThemeCheck](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/). It will display errors, and malicious code (base64, gzdeflate, etc...).

Good Luck.